# Android app for exclusive group

Tags: android

I'm developing an `android` app. Customer would like to offer it through the Market but would like to restrict the usage to only a closed group of users. Basically allowing to use the app only to the people they decide to allow.

How would I go about it?
Emailing `APK` may not be best as it causes problems with phone settings, updates and it can still be forwarded to person outside the closed group.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for that. Problem is that the group is approx 1500 users. At 5$ per user it makes it unfeasible. Any other ideas?